# How to return a gdb.Value() from a string?

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

Consider the following gdb commands that output the same text string.

```
(gdb) print foo
(gdb) python print(gdb.lookup_symbol('foo'))
```

In this case `gdb.lookup_symbol()` returns a `gdb.Value()` instance as expected, and the stringification of it is equivalent to the default gdb stringification.

But now consider the following equivalent case:

```
(gdb) print *&foo
```

The `*&` is a noop, but trying to use `gdb.lookup_symbol('*&foo')` does not work. So my question is whether it is possible to make use of gdb's command line dereferencing parser from python, and then get a `gdb.Value` in return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> trying to use gdb.lookup_symbol('*&foo') does not work.

That's because there is no symbol named `*&foo` in the binary.

> whether it is possible to make use of gdb's command line dereferencing parser from python, and then get a gdb.Value in return?

Your question is not very clear, but I *think* you are asking for [parse_and_eval](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html):

```
Function: gdb.parse_and_eval (expression)
Parse expression, which must be a string, as an expression in the current language,
evaluate it, and return the result as a gdb.Value.

This function can be useful when implementing a new command (see Commands In Python),
as it provides a way to parse the command’s argument as an expression.
It is also useful simply to compute values, for example, it is the only way to get
the value of a convenience variable (see Convenience Vars) as a gdb.Value.
```

Comment: This was indeed exactly what I was looking for. :-)